# Validate a datetime using: Y-m-d H:m:s in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime, date-parsing

Pretty simple question, how do i validate a datetime, so the input is both the correct format, but also a valid date unlike `2015-02-30 ...`.

```
2015-06-28 16:06:35 //Valid
```

Comment: you could parse it with the Date object, stringify the result, and then compare the original to the result. If you put too high a value into Date, it rolls over, so the result would have to be different from the original. Check out the MDN pages on the Date object.

Comment: Have you tried using the Date object i.e. dt = new Date('2015-06-28 16:06:35');. Anything that is invalid will return with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It's quite good at taking an input of something date-like and parsing it into something usable. It also has an `isValid` method for determining if the lib was able to parse the date input it was given.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/

```js
var feb30 = moment('2015-02-30');
var jun28 = moment('2015-06-28');

str = "Feb 30: " + feb30.isValid(); // false
str += "\nJun 28: " + jun28.isValid(); // true

alert(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `var d = new Date('2015-02-30')`, it will roll over and return the date of `2015-03-02`. So, if you compare strings of these values they will be unequal.